# Как добавить свойство в корзину?

Tags: битрикс

Как добавить свойство в корзину? Хочу сделать купить в подарок.

Сабж. Вижу это так:

1. Пользователь жмет кнопку Купить в подарок.
2. Товар добавляется в корзину, и добавляется он с заранее выставленным свойством Куплен в подарок = Да.
3. Далее уже работа менеджера.

Через события, наверное, это как-то делается?

Comment: @Максим Гречушников, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Добавить можно с помощью функции модуля торгового каталога Add2BasketByProductID:

```
CModule::IncludeModule("catalog");
Add2BasketByProductID(
    $PRODUCT_ID, 
    $QUANTITY, 
    array(), 
    array(
        Array(
            "NAME" => "Куплен в подарок",
            "CODE" => "IS_PRESENT",
            "VALUE" => "Да",
            "SORT" => "100",
        )
    )
);
```

либо воспользовавшись штатными возможностями компонента catalog.section.

Через события наверняка тоже как-то можно, но тут вопрос как в событии вы будете отслеживать, что товар добавляется с целью подарка.